# Alternative to hide/show content with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

is there a better way to replace this kind of js function by simply collapse/toggle a div and show/hide its content?

```
$(function() {
           $('#destselect').change(function(){
                $('.dest').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
           });
      });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Check my answer below to understand why this happens. :) You should only wrap with `DOMContentLoaded` the code that has to be run after your page is loaded.

Comment: should that be done in a separate file? I tried to put it at the end, the function now works, but made other stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are loading your script before browser finishes loading [dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) conetent and so when it runs the elements it is trying to add event listeners to, don't yet exist.

Try wrapping all you javascript in that file in this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // all your code goes here
});
```

The above makes sure that your script is run after loading all elements on the page.

Comment: It did work, thanks so much for that clean simple solution :)

Comment: However, one of the scripts contained on the JS file now won't work... Maybe a conflict with the line I just added? The function is the Dropdown Menu. Here's the file www.argentina-fly-com/js/scripts.js

Comment: I just looked at this file. Those two lines of code do the exact same job (one with plain javascript and the second with jQuery)  `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {  
$(document).ready(function() {`   (with corresponding closing tags). But it shouldn't cause any conflict. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks so much! I just made some corrections following your advice and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because your js file is called on the head of your page.

Because of this, when you `document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');`, `colls` result in an empty array, as your elements in body are not yet created.

You could either create a separate js file and add it at the end of your body (in that way you make sure your colls are created when your javascript is executed), or just wrap your code on a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener that will trigger your code once the document has completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script tag to the header of your HTML file, this will import the JS file into your current page as follows 
`<script src="File1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` 
Then call the function either in `onclick` in a button or in another script (usually at the bottom) of your page. Something like this:

```
<body>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">
   functionFromFile1()
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your script is not executing properly due to a missing variable.

In this script https://www.argentina-fly.com/js/scripts.js
`Naves` variable in function `UpdateDetailsDestination()` is not defined.

I think you should resolve this first and then check your further code is working on not.
Please take a look into Console when running page. You'll see all JavaScript related errors there.